# I want to add a Comment box inside the portlet over Liefray

Tags: java, liferay

In my custom portlet I want to show a comment box.

Can we use liferay's comment box ?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can just use a text field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer the link: [Comment functionality for Custom entity](http://pmkathiria.blogspot.com/2013/07/using-liferay-uidiscussion-tag-for-your.html)